# PowerMockito verify static calls to two methods of different classes

Tags: junit, powermock, powermockito

I have a test case where, I need to verify if two static methods of different classes were invoked from the test method

RightNow, when I do like this :

```
        @Test
        public void testFunction () {
        ...
        ...
        object.testMethod(); // call to the main method which in turn calls the two static methods
        // Verifying
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        ClassA.method1(any());
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        ClassB.method1(any());
    }
```

I am getting exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at (redacted)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
```

I have added both the classes A and B in @PrepareForTest and PowerMockito.mockStatic

What is the correct way to verify if two static methods were called during the execution of the method under test ?

Comment: What are the expected data types for your method1 and method2? Also, have you mocked the static class - something like - `PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassA.class) `?

Comment: both the methods are of type Void. Yes I have mocked both of the classes. When I am using verify for either one of the class alone, then the tests pass. But not when I verify both of them at once